# Spring Core Converter: Is source null possible as param in convert method

Tags: spring

[Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html#convert-S-) mentions the `source` can never be null. But in my application `source` could be null, will converter skip converting if the `source` is null. Is that why Spring doc says `source` can never be null

```java
@ReadingConverter
static class LongToDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Long, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convert(Long source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Date(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and did some research on it, here is what I found out.

Firstly, have a look at the documentation for [ConversionService API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#core-convert-ConversionService-API). Notice the following:

> ConversionService defines a unified API for executing type conversion logic at runtime. Converters are often run behind the following facade interface.

This means that the ConversionService is responsible for calling your Converter's convert method.

You can have a look at the [Java docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService.html) for the ConversionService next. We can see there is a convert() method. As stated in the docs, for the convert method of the ConversionService interface, the *source* parameter can be *null* (in contrast to the Converter's convert method).

It seems to me it is this ConversionService implementation that will check if the source parameter is *null*, and return *null* if it is, ensuring that the Converter's convert method will only run if the source parameter is not *null*.

For your question, if you let Spring handle the conversion, say in the context of retrieving data from a form, through Spring MVC, the conversion will run through the ConversionService. In that case, conversion will be skipped if the *source* parameter is *null*.